# how can i click button tags where there is no type = submit or type = button

Tags: python, html, selenium, tags, bots

i'm trying to do a selenium bot, but i got stuck for a few days on how to press a button. i've this piece of code

```
<div class="buttonContainerItem--286mU restrictedMinWidth--1yzrO" data-role="button-container-item">
 <button class="button--3h5xe buttonSizeDefault--3mQ1i buttonStateDefault--3rSF6
 buttonLabelPositionInside--2JRkN buttonIconPositionLeft--2FL2w buttonThemePopup--38gEr
 buttonModeDesktop--i3Cpv buttonFitWidth--2WSgF" data-role="button" tabindex="-1">
  <span data-role="button-bordered" class="bordered--3kSwE roundingBoth--177dl">
   <span data-role="button-label" class="label--2kPAA labelCapitalized--3pF45">OK</span>
  </span>
 </button>
</div>
```

and i don't know how to click on "ok" button, i tried with xpath, selenium ide, click on every tag but none work. I always get the same output: "exception impossible to locate element" something like that. Please anyone could help me?? i found same error on other bot. Do u know how to solve it?

Comment: Please provide error message and write the code for which you get your error.

Comment: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div[10]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.190)

Answer (score 0):

You could click on element using Python, but you have to correct your XPath. Anyway, you could get X-Path from browser when you are in Web Inspector. For that right click on element you want and select "Copy –> XPath" or something similar.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver")
driver.get("file:///Users/BelKed/Desktop/test.html")

ok = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/button")
ok.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking the button with the child span text OK.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[./span/span[.='OK']]").click()
```